Does a moderator have unlimited power to moderate their site?
If I moderated a site, could I fill it with my own sock puppet accounts, prefilled Q&A with subtly wrong answers, and delete only constructive comments (without telling comment authors their comments were deleted)? Or would I be prevented from doing that? If so, by what?

What did your own researches show when you tried to find an answer for yourself? (Bearing in mind you've been around nearly 15 years)

I actually think this is an interesting question: the answer to the last couple of sentences has changed a few times in the past five years.

What a strange question...

Consider - you'd have to win an election first, by convincing a lot of people that you'll be a good moderator.

Are you aware of the difference between moderators and staff?

It'd be an even longer game to get hired to troll a site - so I'm assuming moderators.

UNLIMITED POWER!!!! AHAHAHA!!!

In theory you could do most of these things without being a moderator. One of the nice things about a community run site when we have good engagement is we don't miss things.
I think there's a really important point here. Becoming and being a moderator is work. There's probably hundreds or thousands of hours put in even as a lazy moderator. I don't have time to try to mess up my site for any reason.

my own sock puppet accounts

Well yes. You'd also have to manage different email accounts, maybe proxies. Then SOMEONE notices a small spelling quirk you have and its all over. Quite a few moderators do legitimately have alternate accounts either for testing, or to segregate access between trusted and untrusted answers.
Any user could do this
Maintaining, and remembering to use an alternate account is a lot of work.

prefilled Q&A with subtly wrong answers

People test it, and downvote you. The chatgpt drama aside - which pretty much was people trying to do it in quantity, generally its pretty obvious when someone is posting low quality content. Likewise - its not something that needs a moderator

and delete only constructive comments (without telling comment authors their comments were deleted)?


Useful information belongs in a post. Even constructive comments are not meant to be permanent
Fundamentally - the effort needed to become and be a moderator, and the systems we have in place makes this practically a waste of time. Not even counting the checks and balances, as well as the fact that other than comment deletion, none of this needs to be a moderator function, it would need someone to play a very long game, for no actual practical gain.

I asked if moderators had authority to do this.

All moderators must abide by the moderator agreement - part of that is to abide by the code of conduct

All actions will be taken on a case-by-case basis at the discretion of our moderators. If you’re not satisfied with a moderator decision, you are welcome to appeal it by contacting us directly. We review each report individually and will respond as quickly as we can.

So if you have a problem with the actions you can appeal to staff. Having said that...

Moderators can have sock puppet accounts (as can anyone) provided their accounts do not interact.
Moderators are not infallible and their answers may occasionally contain mistakes just like anyone else.
Comments are generally regarded as pretty much ephemeral regardless of their contents. If you have something valuable to impart, then write an answer to the question and don't just leave a comment. Comment authors are rarely contacted to say their comments are deleted, that's not really useful information unless a moderator had some specific and serious issue with someone's comments. Just because you think your comment is valuable doesn't mean that everyone else does, nor does it mean its value will last forever.

In addition moderators are part of a site moderation team. Your fellow moderators can...

see everything you do as a moderator
undo it if necessary
contact the Community Moderation team if they feel that there's a problem they can't resolve themselves.


"Moderators can have sock puppet accounts (as can anyone) provided their accounts do not interact." One common exception to this (as you've phrased it) is that moderators' sockpuppet accounts are often used as targets when testing moderation actions, in order to avoid disruptively testing it on a real account.  Mine has been suspended 5 times and received 11 mod messages, all from me while testing things.

@RyanM I hope that sockpuppet learned its lesson!

My sock has been suspended for excessive barking :D


could I fill it with my own sock puppet accounts

Under certain circumstances, sockpuppets are permitted.

prefilled Q&A with subtly wrong answers

You could do this, but please try not to. It's not against the rules to be wrong about stuff, provided you aren't doing it on purpose, but past a certain point, you should probably realise that you're not actually a subject matter expert, and stop. (There is no requirement for moderators to be subject matter experts, though it helps.)
Doing this on purpose would be a clear-cut case of vandalism.

delete only constructive comments

While comments are officially temporary, I'd say selectively-deleting constructive comments constitutes vandalism, regardless of who's doing it.

without telling comment authors their comments were deleted

The site doesn't really provide a mechanism to notify comment authors, short of adding another comment (and that usually defeats the point of deleting a comment).

Or would I be prevented from doing that? If so, by what?

The CMs would remove your diamond (and probably suspend your account) quite quickly: they're always on the lookout for compromised moderator accounts. If you were actually doing this kind of thing, you'd be exceedingly unlikely to get the diamond back.
There is also a procedure for your fellow moderators to initiate a coup the moderator removal process, which would be the expected response to a less extreme scenario. I think this has happened before, though we don't discuss such things so I don't know the details.
